# photoswipe: pid/gid link to particular photo

Tags: photoswipe

I wonder how photoswipe builds URL to a particular image in a gallery?

I see that for each image in a gallery the following URL is built: `[BASE_URL]#&gid=2&pid=3`. If I get it right, the pid/gid values are taken in the order of gallery/photo appearance on a page. Which presents problem for dynamic content when galleries/photos are shuffled (sorted, deleted, etc.)

Is there a way to overrule that logic such that static ID's (e.g. database PK's) are used?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After digging into the sources I found out that if gallery element has attribute `data-pswp-uid=` set to some value, then that value is used in URL as `gid`.

Unfortunately, same trick on an image/figure didn't do.